# What values are on the first and the second places of MySQL's POLYGON((first, second))?

Tags: mysql, mercator

I want to populate a table with polygons. I get 8-byte numbers that represent `lat` and `lng`. These numbers are `x` and `y` coordinates. So what goes on the first place and what goes on the second place?

```
var aSrid = sphericalmercator.forward([lng, lat]);  // [x, y] are returned values
```

Now I create MySQL function. What is correct:

```
POLYGON((x y, x y, x y, ...))
or
POLYGON((y x, y x, y x, ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

WKT format uses x and then y

```
POLYGON((x y, x y, x y, ...))
```